# Beginner here: Regarding Ruby on Rails - HOW does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, have so far learnt to develop WordPress websites, and have been developing themes for around 2 years. I would, hoever, like to move into "ACTUAL" web development, rather than WordPress. I have stumbled upon Rails, and have been doing some research, however I still don't know what it would take to create a Website with Rails.

Do I need template files the same way I need them in WordPress? If so, what are the minimum files I would need to put up a website? (e.g. index/home.php, sidebar, header, footer?)
Do I need a deep understanding of SQL?
Can I use Rails with most hosting services?
What is the firs thing I need to understand before I begin to do some practical learning on RoR (I like to learn as I go along - for instance, people starting out learning HTML learn usually by building a website as they go along).

Again, my apologies for asking such a horribly noobish question for those who get very sensitive about this stuff. But I ask that you bear with me, with the knowledge that we are all at one point complete beginners at anything.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails new appname` :) Follow a tutorial, for example:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Beyond that, this question is far too broad.

Comment: Fantastic stuff you guys, I am glad everyone here so far has been so helpful to me. Thank you very much, and I think I will start here (railstutorial.org) to understand how it works. I'm in for a long, hopefully not so bumpy ride!

Answer (score 6):

Rails is quite different from Wordpress at a fundamental level:

- Wordpress is flexible **application software** that can be used for blogging, as a Content Management System for building websites and more.
- Rails is is flexible application **building software**. It is used to build web applications including web sites and more.

For example, you could use Rails to build the equivalent of Wordpress. Wordpress itself was built using an alternative to Rails, php.

**Templates** Yes, both Wordpress and Rails use templates.

- In Wordpress, most of your customization of Wordpress is done using templates.
- In Rails, templates are just one part of your application. Other key parts are models and controllers.

**Other questions/answers**

- Do I need template files the same way I need them in WordPress? Yes, you usually use them, but they are just one part of Rails apps.
- Do I need a deep understanding of SQL? A. You need to understand more about what's going on in the database with Rails than with WP. But you don't need a "deep" level of SQL. Rails handles most all of the sql for you. You do need to understand the ideas of tables, joins, columns, column types and how to choose them.
- Can I use Rails with most hosting services? A. Not as easily as WP. Ask your hosting service to see what their answer is about Rails. There are low cost hosting services that work well with Rails. DreamHost is one.
- What is the firs thing I need to understand before I begin to do some practical learning on RoR (I like to learn as I go along - for instance, people starting out learning HTML learn usually by building a website as they go along). A. Understand the difference between an application (WP) and a programming system that enables you to build applications (Rails).

**Summary** If you can do what you need to do in Wordpress then it is probably a good solution for your task. If you can't accomplish your task using Wordpress, or it seems like too much work to do so, then investigate Rails.

**Next step** I suggest that you get book on Rails and use it to learn the system.

**Added**

Both Wordpress and Rails are fantastic open source projects. I use both and think that they are both great in their own ways.

I would not recommend Rails if you want to build a web content site. I do recommend it if you want to build a web **application.**

- You want to build a website where the pages are static except for a "add me to the email list" form. Use WP.
- You want to build a web page application which enables visitors to donate to a non-profit. Using plugin for WP would probably be the fastest solution. Or get a "Donate button" from Paypal or similar.
- You want to build a *custom* application which enables donors to organize themselves into teams, raise money and graph the on-going competition between the teams. This would be a good use of Rails.

**Rails as a software learning tool** If you want to learn or improve your skills at writing software, Rails is a good choice. It enables you to write large systems in the Ruby language.  WP enables you to use php, but it is much easier to use Ruby to write object oriented software.

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of tutorials on the web, a little [google](http://google.com/search?q=rails%20beginner%20tutorial) will help.

In the meantime, assuming you've installed Rails, generate a simple web application by opening a terminal and typing

```
rails new testapp
```

That will create your rails application - bare bones, of course.

Start your server

```
rails server
```

Then go to

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Take a look at the directories and files on your filesystem and see what is there. Much of it might be confusing, but that's to be expected--you're just starting out. You will be able to learn how it all works by googling and asking questions.

There's a whole lot more to it, but that is the start.  When you get a bit more learning under your belt, make sure you take a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io//) and [bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TryRuby.org](http://TryRuby.org) and [Codeschool.com](http://Codeschool.com) - They will get you up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I also came from Wordpress. I used to love wordpress, but now i realise that i am better off using RoR.

In RoR you can create what you want, or what your client wants. So strongly recommend it.

As for templates. It's not the same. Rails uses partial templates. You can still have the header, footer, the side bar etc.

Have you seen a RoR site before?

@Dave Newtown is right .... http://ruby.railstutorial.org/